# Show that $\cos(2X)$ is equally distributed to $\cos(X)$

Tags: calculus, probability

For $X \sim U[0,2\pi]$, I have tried to show that the MGFs of $\cos(X)$ and $\cos(2X)$ are equal but this does not appear to be working. My next attempt was 
\begin{align}P\left(\cos(X) < x\right) &= P\left(X < \cos^{-1}(x)\right) + P\left(X < \cos^{-1}(-x)\right) \\[0.4cm]&= \frac{\cos^{-1}(x)}{2\pi} + \frac{\cos^{-1}(-x)}{2\pi}\end{align} for $x \in [-1,1]$ and 
\begin{align}P(\cos(2X) < x) &= 2\left[P\left(X < \frac{\cos^{-1}(x)}{2}\right) + P\left(X < \frac{\cos^{-1}(-x)}{2}\right)\right] \\[0.4cm]&= 2\left[ \frac{\cos^{-1}(x)}{4\pi} + \frac{\cos^{-1}(-x)}{4\pi}\right] = \frac{\cos^{-1}(x)}{2\pi} + \frac{\cos^{-1}(-x)}{2\pi}\end{align} for $x \in [-1,1]$, which seems to work.

Thea idea here is that $\cos(x)$ is 1:1 on $[0,\pi]$ and $[\pi,2\pi]$ (hence two seperate terms in the first calculation) while $\cos(2x)$ is 1:1 on $[0,\pi]$ and $[\pi,2\pi]$ and $[2\pi,3\pi]$ and $[3\pi,4\pi]$.(Hence the factor 2 in the second calculation). Is this correct, and if so is it correctly argued?

Comment: Your arguments are not fine. You should discuss wether $x<\pi$ or not (for the first case). Note also that $\arccos (x) + \arccos(-x) = \pi$ for $ x \in [-1,1]$. A more straightforward (not necessarily less involved) way to go about this is to look at charateristic functions.

Comment: @ Math-fun Thank you! I will look into this.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $A=\left\{ x\in\left[0,2\pi\right]\mid\cos x\in B\right\} $
then:

For $x\in\left[0,\pi\right]$ we find: $$\cos2x\in B\iff2x\in A$$
For $x\in\left[\pi,2\pi\right]$ we find: $$\cos2x=\cos\left(4\pi-2x\right)\in B\iff4\pi-2x\in A$$

So if $X\in[0,2\pi]$ then: $$\cos2X\in B\iff X\in\frac12A\cup(2\pi-\frac12A)$$

It remains to prove that: $$\Pr(X\in A)=\Pr\left(X\in\frac12A\cup(2\pi-\frac12A)\right)$$

Comment: Thanks! How am I to interpret $\frac{1}{2}A$?

Comment: As $\{\frac12a\mid a\in A\}$ wich is a subset of $[0,\pi]$. And $2\pi-\frac12A$ as $\{2\pi-\frac12a\mid a\in A\}$ which is a subset of $[\pi,2\pi]$.